# Is a page fault across NUMA nodes "major" or "minor"?

Tags: performance, numa

I understand that on a single-socket Linux system, a command such as `sudo ps -eo min_flt,maj_flt,cmd` will generally count a page fault as "minor" if it blocks on a memory-to-memory copy, or on the zeroing of a deallocated page, or for some reason doesn't touch persistent storage. But is this true on NUMA systems as well, even when the fault requires a data transfer from one NUMA node to another? Or does that cross the line into "major"?

Answer (score 2):

Page faults only count as major if they involve disk access; you can verify that (for Linux) by [searching for `VM_FAULT_MAJOR` in the kernel source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/VM_FAULT_MAJOR).

So even if cross-node memory accesses count as a page fault (I don’t think they do), they don’t count as major faults.